# DB2/400 - Auto generated timestamp on change (error)

Tags: sql, database, db2, db2-400

I'm trying to create a table with a timestamp column that autogenerates with 'current timestamp' on each update of the record. I'm on DB2/400 (version V5R3) using ODBC driver.

That's the query:

```
CREATE TABLE random_table_name ( 
ID                   integer not null generated always as identity,
USERS_ID             varchar (30),
DETAILS              varchar (1000),
TMSTML_CREATE        timestamp  default current timestamp ,
TMSTMP_UPDATE        timestamp not null generated always for each row on update as row change timestamp,
PRIMARY KEY ( ID )
```

)

I get this error (translated):

```
ERROR [42000] [IBM][iSeries Access ODBC Driver][DB2 UDB]SQL0104 - Token EACH not valid. Valid tokens: BIT SBCS MIXED.
```

Without the 'TMSTMP_UPDATE' row the query works. How can i solve this?

---

**EDIT:** Ok, i understand that in my DB2 version, the only way is to use triggers, but today AS400 seems to be evil with me.
I'm trying with this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER random_trigger_name
AFTER UPDATE ON random_table_name
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW_ROW
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
BEGIN ATOMIC
    SET NEW_ROW.TMSTM_UPDATE = CURRENT TIMESTAMP;
END
```

Error (translated):

```
ERROR [42000] [IBM][iSeries Access ODBC Driver][DB2 UDB]SQL0312 - Variable TMSTM_UPDATE not defined or not available.
```

The column TMSTM_UPDATE exist and it's a normal timestamp.

**EDIT 2:** I've solved the trigger problem by replacing 'after' with 'before'. Now everything works as expected. Thank you all!

Comment: What version of DB2?  The expected tokens list indicates it thinks that it's dealing with a character-based column for whatever reason.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse DB2 version V5R3

Comment: Managed to find [an old manual](http://faithwarren.com/images/glazers/committees/SQL/SQL%20Manuals/V5R3_SQL_Reference.pdf) (not that the current ones are much easier to find...).  Syntax isn't supported in your version (probably not until V5R4, definitely by V6), which makes @Dan's answer correct.  Why are you on such an old version (2 major releases, more than 10 years), anyways?

Comment: I'm working for a company that uses this version, i don't know why they use such an old one. Anyways, I'll go with triggers. Thank you!

Comment: I sincerely hope your company does not have to worry about PCI, SOX or HIPPA.  Support for v5r3 ended in 2009; it has not gotten any fixes since.

Comment: No, their use of the database is quite basic...but yes, they have a really old release!

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard way to do it in iSeries DB2. It is documented here: [IBM Knowledge center - Creating a row change timestamp column](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_61/sqlp/rbafysqlprcts.htm)

You should change your table definition to:

```
TMSTMP_UPDATE TIMESTAMP NOT NULL FOR EACH ROW ON UPDATE AS ROW CHANGE TIMESTAMP
```

I am using it in tables in production over V7R2 and it works like a charm :) Hope it will be available for V5R3

**EDIT**

As Charles mentioned below unfortunately this feature is available since DB2 for i V6R1